# Excel: Sumifs Formula, with possible Index Match?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to create a SUMIFS that has the smarts to check a "child" row within a data range, then using the "parent" ID number (listed in the child row) checks the parents data and sums. I've inserted a picture of a table below which gives a dummy data set. The desired results of such a formula would be:

Child with parent in phase 1: $0

Child with parent in phase 2: $80

Child with parent in phase 3: $10

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

[Example Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOfne.png)

Or as text:

```
ID  Type    Parent ID   Phase   Finances
1   Single              1       $10
2   Parent              2       $10
3   Child   2                   $10
4   Single              3       $10
5   Parent              3       $10
6   Child   5                   $10
7   Single              1       $10
8   Parent              2       $10
9   Child   8                   $10
10  Child   8                   $10
11  Child   8                   $10
12  Child   8                   $10
13  Child   8                   $10
14  Child   8                   $10
15  Child   8                   $10
```

Comment: Sample data in a ASCII / text is much more preferable than a screen capture.

Comment: Does the above edit work?

Comment: If my answer below was a misunderstanding, wouldn't the sum of children with parents in phase 2 be 80?  since both parent 8 and parent 2 are both in phase 2?  and the child with parent in phase 1 be  0 since no parent is in phase 1?

Comment: Sorry, you're right... my error. Yes, so based on the above data it should be:

Comment: Child with parent in phase 1: $0

Child with parent in phase 2: $80

Child with parent in phase 3: $10

Comment: is it permissible to assign a phase to the child based on the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is in A1 to E16.

Generate a helper column which fills in the blank phases.  The blank phases will be filled in assuming that they have the same phase as the parent ID.  Therefore in F1 place the following formula ans copy down to F16:

```
=IF(D2<>"",D2,VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$D$16,4,0))
```

Now we can use a sumproduct and take the total of only children and phase 2.  In H1 to J3 I built I summary table of what you were looking for. In H1 to J1 I used headers and in H2 to I 4 I defined what I was searching for.  In J2 to J4 I used the a formula for determine the finances as follows:

```
Type   |  Phase  |  Finance
Child  |    1    |  =SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$16=H2)*($F$2:$F$16=I2)*$E$2:$E$16)
Child  |    2    |  =SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$16=H3)*($F$2:$F$16=I3)*$E$2:$E$16) 
Child  |    3    |  =SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$16=H4)*($F$2:$F$16=I4)*$E$2:$E$16)
```

The sumproduct only totals the rows from your table where there is CHILD (as defined in column H) and phase equal to the number defined in I, and only sums the values that correspond in your finance columns.  If either child is not present in B or or the phase in F is not equal to what number is being searched than that row is valued as 0.

Proof of concept

[image: Proof of Concept]

Comment: Upvoted, although I would have avoided calling the column PHASE and instead gone for "parent-phase" to avoid the confusion. And also I would have used and index/match instead of vlookup, but that might be because I love index/match.

Comment: @StianYttervik Agreed that index/match is more versatile, but in this case with the data layed out the way it is vlookup is fewer arguments to type in.  As for column naming, originally I had it blank....got lazy and just retyped the old one...At least I accidently had cap locks on! 8)

Comment: This is great thanks and the answer works. For arguments sake, is there anyway this could be done without entering a new column (like you have with column F) and all the logic was withheld in the formula?

Comment: Not that I am currently aware of.  I'll see if I can get someone else to look at it.

Comment: @Andy_NPT see my answer.  ForwardEd, you called I answered.

Comment: @ScottCraner  must be a lot of concrete in your neck of the woods 8).  Thanks for the alternative answer, I will be taking a deeper look into it momentarily.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in one array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($C$2:$C$16<>"",(LOOKUP($C$2:$C$16,$A$2:$A$16,$D$2:$D$16)=G2)*$E$2:$E$16))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when leaving edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: That's awesome. I have one more question. Would that formula work if you added a if/and statement like such:

Comment: =SUM(IF(AND($C$2:$C$16<>"",$B$2:$B$16="CHILD"),(LOOKUP($C$2:$C$16,$A$2:$A$16,$D$2:$D$16)=G2)*$E$2:$E$16))

Comment: I might have a situation where you get two types of "child" data and the formula will need to distinguish.... I'm trying on my data set and it's not quite working.

Comment: Array formulas do not like `And` and `Or`.  So we need use `*` and `+` in their places so `=SUM(IF(($C$2:$C$16<>"")*($B$2:$B$16="CHILD"),(LOOKUP($C$2:$C$16,$A$2:$A$16,$D$2:$D$16)=G2)*$E$2:$E$16))` @Andy_NPT